# How to call my own method in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, methods

I am trying to get the Web-URL in my JSP File, the method works, when I call it in HTML like:`

```
</br>
<%=getParameter(request, "requestID")%>
</br>
```

When I call my method in my jspInit method, I get an error, anyone know how it could fix, here is the code:

```
<%!
    public String getParameter(HttpServletRequest request, String param) {
        String result = request.getParameter(param);
        return result.replace("&", "&amp;").replace("\"", "&quot;").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;").replace("'","$#039;");
    }
%>

<%!  
    public void jspInit(){
        String temp = getParameter(request, "requestID");
    }
%>
```

The error:

```
JBWEB004211: Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:85)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:69)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:326)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:606)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reinventing the wheel. It seems you want to display a parameter value, and escape HTML symbols in the parameter value.

The JSP EL allows getting a parameter value.

The JSTL's c:out tag, and thge JTSL's fn:escapeXml function, both escape HTML symbols.

So all you need (after properly [installing the JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)) and declaring the usage of the c or fn tag library in the JSP, is

```
<c:out value="${param.requestID}"/>
```

or

```
${fn:escapeXml(param.requestID)}
```

Scriptlets were cool in 1998. 2 years later (IIRC), their usage was discouraged in favor of custom tags, then the JSP EL and the JSTL.

Comment: I want to export the String to a txt File, I have the code to do it, but I can't get the value, that the mothod returns

Comment: Exporting a string to a text file, whatever that might mean, is not the job of a JSP. It's the job of Java code called from a controller (a servlet for example). The role of a JSP is to generate HTML from a model.

Comment: Thank you, I got it, the connection with the Servlet works